# Copy database from assets folder to android , updating it and copying it back to asset folder

Tags: android-sqlite

I have copied sqlite database from assets folder to datasbases folder of my android app. I have updated the data in one of the tables of database too based on user input data.Now I want to replace sqlite database in assets folder with updated database from databases folder of my app. kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the assets folder is part of the APK, it is read only. You would have to regenerate the APK using the updated database.

Accessing the updated database itself could be an issue as the App's data is protected in devices that aren't rooted.

If you are using a device connected to Android Studio then you may be able to copy the updated database file(s) using device explorer into the asses folder. Noting that if the database uses Write-Ahead logging (WAL) that you may have the added complication of the `-wal` and `-shm` files, if there are any uncommitted changes. Ideally you would ensure that the database is closed, this should commit all changes, the -wal file should should then be 0 bytes or not exist in which case it is safe to just copy the database file itself.